# Format data to run ANOVA in R

Tags: r, dataframe, anova

I am trying to run a 3-way ANOVA in R, but my values for each variable are in one column and not separated by rows. Currently, my data frame looks something like this:

```r
Season  Site    Location    Replicate   Lengths
Jan_16  MI      Adj        1.00      ,
Jan_16  MI      Adj        2.00      ,
Jan_16  MI      Adj        3.00      ,
Jan_16  MI     Away        1.00      3,4,
Jan_16  MI     Away        2.00      ,
Jan_16  MI     Away        3.00      ,
Jan_16  MP     Adj         1.00      4,5,6,5,4,5,4,4,4,4,5,4,6,4,
Jan_16  MP     Adj         2.00      4,4,3,3,5,4,3,4,5,3,4,3,4,3,4,6,
Jan_16  MP     Adj         3.00      4,6,5,5,4,
Jan_16  MP     Away        1.00      ,4,4,10,4,5,4,6,5,5,
Jan_16  MP     Away        2.00       3,4,4,4,5,5,4,5,
Jan_16  MP     Away        3.00       4,4,13,4,
```

`Lengths` is the response variable that I wish to run the ANOVA on, how would I do this? Just a "," means there is no data.

**** EDIT

I have tried separate rows

```html
library(tidyr)

separate_rows(data.frame, Season:Replicate, Lengths, convert=numeric )


#Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements
```

The Lengths have a different number of variables, so is there a way to unnest this?

Comment: Think through what you need your data to look like in order to do ANOVA. I'm guessing you want to split the items in `Lengths` so that each row will have a single value. `tidyr::separate_rows` is one function that can do this. It would be best if you can work out how you get started writing code and add that to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unnesting the data was the best solution to the problem.

Running the code:

```html
library(dplyr)

#Unnest everything so that no longer "," but each has a row


data.frame.new<-data.frame   
  transform(Lengths=strsplit(Lengths,",")) %>%
  unnest(Lengths)

#Gets rid of blanks where there are no data

Set.unnest<-subset(data.frame.new, Lengths!="")
```

This gives the result of repeated rows for the Season, Site, Location, and Replicate for each data point in Lengths

Answer (score 0):

**It's not clear from your question what your independent variables are. In the following example, I assume `Site`, `Location`, `Replicate` are your IVs.**

Let's first split entries in `Lengths` into different rows, and remove rows with missing/no `Lengths`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df.aov <- df %>%
    mutate(Lengths = str_split(Lengths, ",")) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(Lengths >= 0)
```

We can now perform a 3-way ANOVA with `aov`

```
res <- aov(Lengths ~ Site * Location * Replicate, data = df.aov)
res
#Call:
#   aov(formula = Lengths ~ Site * Location * Replicate, data = df.aov)
#
#Terms:
#                     Site  Location Replicate Location:Replicate Residuals
#Sum of Squares    2.21675   7.61905   0.11491            0.89526 131.58506
#Deg. of Freedom         1         1         1                  1        53
#
#Residual standard error: 1.57567
#3 out of 8 effects not estimable
#Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

Note that results are not very sensible. I assume that your actual dataset is larger.